# VNC into an existing X2Go LXDE session

Tags: debian, x11vnc

I'm trying to VNC into an already running LXDE session, started through X2Go.
This is a remote VM, running Debian.
I'm usually using X2Go client for Windows but sometimes need to log on through Android (which doesn't have a native client) or another machine that doesn't have X2Go but usually has some sort of VNC viewer.

I've already set up X11vnc and can connect normally to the currently running session.

The problem is that it only works while the X2Go client connected too.
If it's just the VNC viewer, it gets one screen update but never refreshes.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the specific session getting suspended when X2Go disconnects, but don't know where to go from there.